# Excel VBA Copy and pasting cells with certain values in a range from one worksheet to another

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, copy, paste

I am trying to loop through a range of cells and copy and paste the values of the ones that are not blank or do not contain an "X" (as well as the cell two to the right of it) to columns on another worksheet. I am hoping that the cells I paste them to will retain the pre-formatted conditional formatting set up prior to having stuff pasted to them. What I have so far is not working, and does not account for the cell two adjacent to the copy cell or just pasting the value without formatting. It would be great if then I could sort the first of the pairs of cells by alphabetically (also not accounted for). Thanks for any help!

```
Sub Wire_List_Export()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
Dim c As Range
Dim j As Integer

Set copySheet = Worksheets("LV Schedule")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("test")

For Each c In copySheet.Range("G274:G10000")
    If Not c = "X" Or Not IsEmpty(c) Then
        copySheet.Cells(c).Copy pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Before anything else: you are missing a Application.ScreenUpdating = True. Checking the rest of the code.

Comment: You want to copy those cells that are not empty OR do not have a "X" within. In such case, having an "X" in it makes them not empty. At the same time, empty cells do not contain "X". Basically you are copying the entire range. Do you confirm you want not empty cells OR not "X" filled cells? Do you want instead to look for not empty cells AND not "X" filled cells?

Comment: What do you mean with "cell two to the right of it"? You mean the range H274:H10000? Also i guess you want to past the results in range A1:B9727 of the test sheet, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Sub Wire_List_Export()

    'Declarations.
    Dim RngCopyRange As Range
    Dim IntOffsetCopy As Integer
    Dim RngPasteRange As Range
    Dim RngCell As Range

    'Turning off screen updating.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Setting variables.
    Set RngCopyRange = Worksheets("LV Schedule").Range("G274:H10000")
    Set RngPasteRange = Worksheets("test").Range("A1:B9727")

    'Copying the range.
    RngCopyRange.Copy

    'Pasting the range (only values, skipping blank cells).
    RngPasteRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                               Operation:=xlNone, _
                               SkipBlanks:=True, _
                               Transpose:=False

    'Turning off cut-copy mode.
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Turning on screen updating.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```